# Existe algum aspecto na minha resposta que poderia justificar o voto negativo?

Tags: debate

Há uns dias respondi a seguinte questão: [Pegando o total em pixels de um elemento passado em variável em porcentagem](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/179261/pegando-o-total-em-pixels-de-um-elemento-passado-em-vari%C3%A1vel-em-porcentagem).

É impossível saber o motivo pelo qual o utilizador negativou a resposta, somente ele poderia responder essa questão, mas a minha intenção é endenter se a [minha resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/179268/6630) realmente merece votos negativos ao vosso entender, mas antes gostaria que considerassem o seguinte:

- A pergunta do utilizador parte do pressuposto que a `API` do jQuery está retornando um valor errado.
- A minha resposta não resolve o problema diretamente, mas tem a intenção de alertar o utilizador sobre o equívoco, como podem constatar nos comentários à minha resposta.

Se partirmos do princípio que a resposta não resolve o problema diretamente, então a [resposta escolhida](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/179267/6630) também não resolve, uma vez que propõe uma nova solução - altura em proporção a largura do elemento - e não trata o problema - método `width` do jQuery retornando valor em porcentagem.

Não é minha intenção discutir se a resposta selecionada é válida ou não, é a escolha do autor e respeito isso; também não é se a resposta escolhida tem mérito ou não, até porque é útil e vou utilizá-la.

A questão que coloco é: **ao vosso entender, existe algum aspecto na minha resposta que poderia justificar o voto negativo?**

Comment: Na minha opinião está ok. Como sugestão, prefira usar os *snippets* do stack overflow ao invés do JSFiddle. No seu caso não é um problema pois são somente exemplos, mas suponha um caso que o trecho de código é a solução para o problema e, por algum motivo o link quebre...

Comment: Eu acabei de dar um upvote, mas compartilho da opinião do Renan, sério, por que não StackSnippet (trecho de código)?

Comment: Ao meu ver não a nada de errada com a sua resposta. A momentos que não da para saber o motivo do -1, mas tem que seguir em frente mesmo assim. Se vc acha que pode melhorar a resposta, vc pode edita-la.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento obrigado pela edição na resposta, realmente é melhor, vou passar a usar essa solução.

Comment: @FilipeMoraes eu teria uma lista imensa de perguntas negativadas que não consigo ver razão para -1 também (de vários usuários), mas apesar de ser longe do ideal que isto ocorra, faz parte. Assim como o site tem uma quantidade boa de coisas erradas com positivo. Sugiro não se prender demais a isto, considere como "ruído" apenas. Quanto à resposta, em geral está correta, mas tem alguns efeitos colaterais quando você "empilha" coisas com porcentagem dentro de outras com porcentagem, então algum leitor pode ter testado e caido algum desses casos, e entendido que estava errada (é uma suposição).

Comment: @Bacco sim, eu entendo que o voto negativo ocorre algumas vezes sem razão, mas a minha preocupação é se realmente haveria algo errado com minha resposta. Eu não ignoro o voto negativo, vejo como um alerta mas nesse caso parece-me mais um falso alarme.

Comment: Usar o negativo como oportunidade para procurar melhoria e revisar o post é sempre bom, basta não se prender "emocionalmente" :)

Answer (score 8):

Logo nas 3 primeiras palavras eu vi algo que poderia ser o motivo do negativo.

A resposta começa com: "Você está equivocado...".

Isso é o suficiente até para iniciar uma guerra.

Esse tipo de colocação afeta o ego da pessoa que fica irracional, emotiva e consequentemente não consegue ler ou interpretar todo o restante e vai direto no botão de negativo.

Quando uma pessoa fica nervosa e emotiva, o cérebro cria um bloqueio, dificultando parcial ou totalmente o lado racional e lógico.

Lidamos com pessoas e, pessoas são emotivas. Portanto, evite quaisquer colocações que possam afetar emotivamente alguém, mesmo que seja algo tão insignificante como o seu caso.

Minha experiência aqui, eu já escrevi respostas boas onde estavam positivando e elogiando, aí nos comentários escrevi algo com intuito de ofender mesmo.. rsrs.. No começo aqui eu era meio zuera mesmo. Na ocasião o cara enchia o saco com abestagem. Aí ele negativou a resposta que outrora elogiou e positivou. Até removeu o status de resolvido. Ou seja, impera o lado emotivo.

Em outros casos, foi sem querer, quando você critica algo, mesmo sem o menor intuito de ofender, a pessoa leva para o emocional e lasca um negativo. Isso se agrava quando essa pessoa mantém uma rede de amigos dentro do site e combinam de votarem em grupo. Uma atitude infantil mas é muito comum.

Por fim, seja comedido em tudo que posta. Evite criticar qualquer coisa mesmo que tenha razão, e isso o afastará desses negativos emotivos.

Sempre que receber negativo, evite ficar de "mimimi". Principalmente nos comentários pois isso normalmente não resolve nada. Apenas perde tempo, gera transtorno e até cria inimizades.

Aproveite e procure editar tudo o que postou de um jeito que não dê chances de alguém negativar. Outros que lerem a resposta vão perceber que os negativos e os comentários ruins não batem e acabam por positivar.

As vezes ninguém vai positivar e cai no esquecimento e fica lá negativado mesmo. Quanto a isso, tanto faz. Siga em frente.

Veja que essa minha resposta também possui elementos que podem me trazer votos negativos pois critico de forma indireta usando termos como "infantil, afeta o ego, bla bla bla". Naqueles onde a carapuça servir, pode ser ofensivo. Mas não me importo e não acredito que um usuário são (mentalidade sadia) se ofenda com isso.

O importante é transmitir a mensagem de forma transparente e quem age com muita emotividade, que procure se controlar emocionalmente ou consulte um psiquiatra.

## Má interpretação

É importante estar ciente também quem nem sempre trata-se de algo emotivo. Pode ser má interpretação. Nesse caso, é também um indicador de que a postagem deve ser revisada. Procure quaisquer pontos onde pode estar levando um ou outro usuário a má interpretação e adapte para algo mais consistente. Procure também por coisas mínimas, por exemplo, textos que podem transparecer arrogância, presunção, etc, também são motivos de negativos.

Comment: Tens razão Daniel. Acabei por remover da resposta a colocação inicial, realmente as pessoas podem levar para o lado pessoal. Obrigado pela dica.

Comment: +1 pela aula de psicologia...